# Finding fixed size submatrix with highest sum

Tags: matrices, subset-sum

I have a matrix, which has N rows and M columns. I need to find n rows and m columns, which has the highest sum. Matrix consists of positive numbers. Not optimal solutions are ok. For example N=M=4; n=m=3

A=$\begin{bmatrix}13 & 83 & 93 & 1
\\70 & 84 & 37 & 38
\\24 & 68 & 78 & 25
\\30 & 47 & 87 & 89\end{bmatrix}$

The highest sum (571) is by removing 1st row and 0th column. Currently I take first n rows by sum and m first columns by sum within current n rows. What alternative methods could I use?

Comment: I don't understand well your current method. Are you selecting greedily the rows first ? Which may be not optimal of course.

Comment: Your problem is NP-complete.
Consider the adjacency matrix $A$ of an unweighted graph $G=(V,E)$ so that $N=M=|V|$.
Choose a parameter $k$ and let $n=m=k$.

There is a $n \times m$ submatrix $B$ of $I+A$ whose elements sum to at least $k^2$ iff $G$ contains a clique of size $k$.